# Google maps: Bind params to click event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps JavaScript API to add markers onto a map.  For each marker I'm adding a listener to the click event on each one.  Below is my code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var marker = addMarker(markers[0]); //The addMarker function contains the code to add the marker

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

I also want to bind the `i` param to the click event so that when it fires I can do something with the value in `i` (I'll change this to be a different variable later).  However which ever marker I click on the console **always logs out the last value of i**.

So for each iteration of the loop it's overwriting the callback for the click event.  Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: you should be wrapping your event assignment inside a closure

Comment: @Roljhon I don't fully understand closures, would you be able to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you want using closures. This will preserved the `i` when you do the click.

**Note the below are only an example to point out the idea.**

```js
var markers = ["marker1","marker2","marker3"];
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      var marker = addMarker(markers[i]); //The addMarker function contains the code to add the marker
      (function(_i,marker){
        marker.addEventListener('click', function() {
            alert(_i);
       });
      })(i,marker)
}

function addMarker(marker){
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.id = marker;
    elem.textContent = marker;
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    return elem;
}
```